State machine question in C, why it pauses?
This simple code tries to move through a 2 by 2 matrix in a spiral manner from index [0][0] until there is no elements left in the original.
For example if there is a matrix like below,
[[1 2 3]  
[4 5 6]  
[7 8 9]]

The output would be,
[1 2 3 6 9 8 7 4 5]
This code runs ok but it pauses briefly in the last and then finally print the output array.
What is the cause of this behavior?
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef enum {
    move_right,
    move_down,
    move_left,
    move_up
}States;

void print_array(int* arr, int n)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        printf(" %d", arr[i]);
    }
}

void spiral_matrix(int* input, int row_size, int col_size, int* output)
{
    int size = row_size * col_size;
    int max_col = col_size-1;
    int max_row = row_size-1;
    int min_col = 0;
    int min_row = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    States current_state = move_right;
    int idx = 0;
    while(idx < size) {
        switch (current_state)
        {
        case move_right:
            if(j < max_col) {
                output[idx] = *(input+i*col_size + j);
                j++;
                idx++;
            } else {
                current_state = move_down;
                min_row += 1;
            }
            break;
        case move_down:
            if(i < max_row) {
                output[idx] = *(input+i*col_size + j);
                i++;
                idx++;
            } else {
                current_state = move_left;
                max_col--;
            }
            break;
        case move_left:
            if(j > min_col) {
                output[idx] = *(input+i*col_size + j);
                j--;
                idx++;
            } else {
                current_state = move_up;
                max_row--;
            }
            break;
        case move_up:
            if(i > min_row) {
                output[idx] = *(input+i*col_size + j);
                i--;
                idx++;
            } else {
                current_state = move_right;
                min_col += 1;
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }   
    }
}
#define N 4
#define M 4

void main(void)
{
    int A[N][M] = {{1,2,3,4},
                    {5,6,7,8},
                    {9,10,11,12},
                    {13,14,15,16}};
    int* spiral_out = (int*)malloc(N*M*sizeof(int));
    spiral_matrix(A[0], N, M, spiral_out);
    print_array(spiral_out, N*M);
    free(spiral_out);
}



Your declaration for main is incorrect.  main is int-valued.  If you enable warnings, your compiler should give one for this.

@TomKarzes Fixing that didn't address the issue here.

If it was confidently given as a fix for the problem your question is about, it would have been an answer, not a comment. Comments aren't held to the same requirements that answers are -- it's acceptable for a comment to focus on problems other than the one that led to the question being asked.

BTW, one thing I do notice here is you're never printing a trailing newline. Because stdout is line-buffered by default (when attached to a TTY -- when going to a file it's fully buffered), when you don't print a newline your output can sit in the buffer until it's finally flushed just before exit.

(that's not unique to C -- it's true in all programming languages that inherit libc's behavior in setting up buffering on stdout and stderr, which is most of them).

Looks like it ends up in an endless loop to me. https://godbolt.org/z/7qE7G7684

@KyuhyongYou Of course it didn't.  Did you think I was actually suggesting that would solve your problem?  I was pointing out a beginner's mistake that you'd made.  It wasn't meant to solve your problem.

@TomKarzes "Your declaration for main is incorrect" is not certainly correct as C allows void main(void) with "or in some other implementation-defined manner.".  IAC, this is a side issue to OP's concern.

@chux-ReinstateMonica Standard C allows either int main(void) or int main(int argc, char *argv[]), or the equivalent.  Anything else is non-standard and considered incorrect.  Whether or not some implementations happen to "allow it" is irrelevant.  gcc issues a warning when it sees it (if warnings are enabled), and the exit code may not be zero (e.g. I saw exit code 250).  I'd call that a problem.  And yes, the fact that this is a side issue has already been explained.  One of the most common uses for comments is to mention side issues that don't answer the question.

@chux-ReinstateMonica So to reiterate, the declaration of main in the original post is incorrect.  Perhaps looking at this answer might help you to understand it better.

@TomKarzes Those answers are not supported by the C spec.  Perhaps "or in some other implementation-defined manner." from C23dr 5.1.2.2.1 2 will.  IAC, this is a side issue.  The fact that it compiles for OP indicates that this is not the key issue.

@chux-ReinstateMonica I said it was a side issue.  You said it was a side issue. I repeated that it was a side issue.  You repeated that it was a side issue.  Can we stop agreeing that it's a side issue now?  I simply pointed out that it was not standard C.  It is not portable.  Maybe some implementations allow it.  If it is not supported by all standard-compliant C implementations, then it is not standard C, by definition, and people should avoid it unless they have an extremely good reason for writing non-standard C.

@TomKarzes Let us see what we agree on: C specifies allows int main(void), int main(int argc, char *argv[]) and the equivalent are OK.  C also specifies or in some other implementation-defined manner.  Using an implementation defined form reduces portability.  This one you may/may not agree: OP's compiler, operating in a C compliant fashion, can compile that code if it allows that implementation-defined  form .

@chux-ReinstateMonica That comment in the standard about "or in some other implementation-defined manner" doesn't really have any effect on what is standard C and what is not. Basically all they're saying is "it has come to our attention that some implementations support non-standard forms of main as an extension to the C language". I find it odd that they bothered including it at all, but I guess they wanted to make people aware that there are non-standard extensions out there. But that applies to any extension to the C language.

@chux-ReinstateMonica (cont) In the case of gcc, it will compile any form of main you choose to use. Whether or not the result works when called in the normal way depends on the calling sequence.  For example, you can declare it float if you like.  You can even define your own private structure foo, then declare struct foo main.  The warning is identical as for void main.  In the case of void main, typically calling a void function as if it were an int function "works", except the return value is garbage.  That's what we see in Linux gcc.  Not "supported", but "works".

@chux-ReinstateMonica (second cont) But the return value is garbage, so you'd want to avoid returning from main and instead call exit to exit the program.  But gcc doesn't "support" this.  It just happens to "work".  Using void main is a mistake since there's no reason for it and it's not standard C.  In most cases it "works" except the exit status is garbage.  As I said from the beginning, using void main is a common beginner's mistake.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

OK @TomKarzes I understood. I made mistake. thanks for pointing out the very obvious problem.


This code runs ok but it pauses briefly in the last and then finally print the output array. What is the cause of this behavior?

That's only your assumption and it is missing facts.
There is a flaw in your logic -
When printing the first row 1,2,3,4, it only writes till element 3 to output array and set the current_state to move_down and in move_down case, writes 4 to output array. But logically it should write till element 4 and then set current_state to move_down. Same behavior for all the corner elements when traversing matrix in spiral manner.
When it reaches to last element, the values of variables max_col, max_row, min_col, min_row, i, j, idx set in such a way that neither while loop condition results in false nor any of the if condition in while loop body results in true and value of variables max_col, max_row, min_col and min_row either increment or decrement based on else block statement. At one stage, they either overflow/underflow (depends on whether its incrementing/decrementing) and end up in undefined behavior.
[An undefined behavior includes it may execute incorrectly (either crashing or silently generating incorrect results), or it may fortuitously do exactly what the programmer intended.]
Values of variables max_col, max_row, min_col, min_row, i, j, idx after writing element 11 (second last element in spiral traversal) in output array (recorded only for a few iterations):
max_col : 1, max_row : 2, min_col : 1, min_row : 2, i : 2, j : 1, idx : 15
max_col : 1, max_row : 1, min_col : 1, min_row : 2, i : 2, j : 1, idx : 15
max_col : 1, max_row : 1, min_col : 2, min_row : 2, i : 2, j : 1, idx : 15
max_col : 1, max_row : 1, min_col : 2, min_row : 3, i : 2, j : 1, idx : 15
max_col : 0, max_row : 1, min_col : 2, min_row : 3, i : 2, j : 1, idx : 15
max_col : 0, max_row : 0, min_col : 2, min_row : 3, i : 2, j : 1, idx : 15
max_col : 0, max_row : 0, min_col : 3, min_row : 3, i : 2, j : 1, idx : 15
max_col : 0, max_row : 0, min_col : 3, min_row : 4, i : 2, j : 1, idx : 15
max_col : -1, max_row : 0, min_col : 3, min_row : 4, i : 2, j : 1, idx : 15
max_col : -1, max_row : -1, min_col : 3, min_row : 4, i : 2, j : 1, idx : 15
max_col : -1, max_row : -1, min_col : 4, min_row : 4, i : 2, j : 1, idx : 15
max_col : -1, max_row : -1, min_col : 4, min_row : 5, i : 2, j : 1, idx : 15
max_col : -2, max_row : -1, min_col : 4, min_row : 5, i : 2, j : 1, idx : 15
max_col : -2, max_row : -2, min_col : 4, min_row : 5, i : 2, j : 1, idx : 15
max_col : -2, max_row : -2, min_col : 5, min_row : 5, i : 2, j : 1, idx : 15
max_col : -2, max_row : -2, min_col : 5, min_row : 6, i : 2, j : 1, idx : 15
max_col : -3, max_row : -2, min_col : 5, min_row : 6, i : 2, j : 1, idx : 15
max_col : -3, max_row : -3, min_col : 5, min_row : 6, i : 2, j : 1, idx : 15
max_col : -3, max_row : -3, min_col : 6, min_row : 6, i : 2, j : 1, idx : 15
......
......
...... // keep on incrementing/decrementing in same pattern 
...... // and loop iterates as there is no change in idx value

The while loop continuously iterates, gives you an impression of pause.
To fix this problem, when changing the current_state, set i (row) and j (column) properly based on the state to be execute:
    while(idx < size) {
        switch (current_state)
        {
        case move_right:
            if(j <= max_col) {     // write to array till max column
                output[idx] = *(input+i*col_size + j);
                j++;
                idx++;
            } else {
                current_state = move_down;
                j = max_col; i++;  // if moving down, increment row and set column to max
                min_row += 1;
            }
            break;
        case move_down:
            if(i <= max_row) {         // write to array till max row
                output[idx] = *(input+i*col_size + j);
                i++;
                idx++;
            } else {
                current_state = move_left;
                i = max_row; j--;  // if moving left, set row to max and  decrement column
                max_col--;
            }
            break;
        case move_left:
            if(j >= min_col) {         // write to array till min column
                output[idx] = *(input+i*col_size + j);
                j--;
                idx++;
            } else {
                current_state = move_up;
                j = min_col; i--;  // if moving up, set column to min and decrement row
                max_row--;
            }
            break;
        case move_up:
            if(i >= min_row) {       // write to array till min row
                output[idx] = *(input+i*col_size + j);
                i--;
                idx++;
            } else {
                current_state = move_right;
                i = min_row; j++;  // if moving right, set row to min and increment column
                min_col += 1;
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }   

The spiral traversal of a matrix can be implemented in much better and simpler way but you have tagged your question with state-machine, so I am assuming, you have intentionally included current_state in your code which is not at all required.

EDIT:
Fellow SO contributor @David C. Rankin added a comment -
I'm a bit lost on why current_state isn't needed -- you need a switch(var) regardless of that you call it. What is the point I"m obviously missing?
Below is the explanation:
Neither we need to maintain the current state nor we need to set next state at the end of current state when traversing a matrix in spiral manner because the traversal scheme itself define the path to traverse and the required information for every ring, like start/end row and start/end column, is already available.
E.g. Clockwise spiral traversal of a matrix -
Start from element at index [0][0] and traverse the outermost ring based on given number of rows and columns of matrix i.e. move right and traverse all elements of matrix till last column, then move down and traverse all elements of matrix till last row, then move left and traverse all elements of matrix till first column, then move up and traverse all elements of matrix till second row.
Now, if there are elements remain inside the ring traversed, reset the start/end row and start/end column and repeat the traversal again.
Here, no need to maintain any state and for every nested ring to traverse, start/end row and start/end column calculation is straight forward.
Demonstration:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 4
#define M 4

void print_array (int * arr, int n) {
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf (" %d", arr[i]);
    }
    printf ("\n");
}

void spiral_matrix (int rows, int cols, int input[rows][cols], int * output) {
    int size = rows * cols;
    int row_max = rows;
    int col_max = cols;
    int row_min = 0;
    int col_min = 0;
    int idx = 0;

    while (idx < size) {
        for (int j = col_min; j < col_max; ++j) {
            output[idx++] = input[row_min][j];
        }

        for (int j = row_min + 1; j < row_max; ++j) {
            output[idx++] = input[j][col_max - 1];
        }

        for (int j = col_max - 1; j > col_min ; --j) {
            output[idx++] = input[row_max - 1][j - 1];
        }

        for (int j = row_max - 1; j > row_min + 1; --j) {
            output[idx++] = input[j - 1][row_min];
        }

        row_max = row_max - 1;
        col_max = col_max - 1;
        row_min = row_min + 1;
        col_min = col_min + 1;
    }
}

int main (void) {
    int A[N][M] = {{1,2,3,4},
                    {5,6,7,8},
                    {9,10,11,12},
                    {13,14,15,16}};

    int * spiral_out = malloc (N * M * sizeof (int));

    if (!spiral_out) {
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    spiral_matrix (N, M, A, spiral_out);
    print_array (spiral_out, N * M);
    free (spiral_out);

    return 0;
}

Output:
# ./a.out 
 1 2 3 4 8 12 16 15 14 13 9 5 6 7 11 10


Good write-up. I'm a bit lost on why current_state isn't needed -- you need a switch(var) regardless of that you call it. What is the point I"m obviously missing?

@DavidC.Rankin I have updated my post and included the explanation. Check the EDIT part.

@H.S. Thank you for your very thoughtful answer to my question.
I realized I need to be more careful when dealing with corner cases.
